# Keyboard hides EditText

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I'm writing an app that has a chat and it looks as follows:

[image]

For some reason, the keyboard hides the lower part of the `EditText`. Also, it seems like it hides the last 2 messages in the chat.

The XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChatActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_Messages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_Message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_rounded"
            android:fontFamily="@font/assistant"
            android:hint="Type a message"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.85"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_Send"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
            style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_path_2830"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1"/>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Is there a reason for it?

In my manifest I have:

```
<activity android:name=".ChatActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

**EDIT:** From what I noticed, the keyboard is opened exactly to the bottom of the text inside the EditText. Since that text is in the middle of the EditText, it seems like it hides the lower gray part. So from my understanding, there is a need for it to start from the bottom of the outside of the EditText, Like from the outside shape of the EditText and not from where text begins.

For example it starts here;

[image]

Instead of:

[image]

From what I understand I need something like "bottom margin" from the keyboard.

**Just to make it clear** - I know about `AdjustResize/AdjustPan`. `AdjustResize` shrinks my `EditText` so I'm trying to avoid it. `AdjustPan` does the job however it moves the screen to the bottom of the TEXT! the bottom of the text is not the bottom of the `EditText`. That's what I'm trying to achieve so `AdjustPan` doesn't just solve the problem. Adding `marginBottom` also does not solve the problem because it just makes AdjustPan move the screen to move again to the bottom of the text. I'm trying to "fool" `AdjustPa`n or to add it some bias.

Thank you

Comment: Please could you try giving some margin bottom value like 16dp to the top level constraint layout

Comment: I tried adding: android:layout_marginBottom="16dp but it didn't work mate.

Comment: Have you tried changing android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: Hi @Ben could you please share with us your solution

Answer (score 1):

Try with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your Manifest.

Comment: AdjustResize indeed makes the keyboard below the edittext, however, the size of the EditText shrinks to a tiny edittext.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest put this in your perticular activity:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Or this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

Comment: As I wrote in my question, this line already exists in my code. it doesnt work. It goes to the bottom of the text inside my EditText but since the lower part of the text and the lower part of the shape of the EditText does not the same, it looks like it hides it.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest put

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Also if only adding above didn't solve your problem or, try to give "bottom margin" to your edit text or layout in which edit text is placed.

Let's say

```
 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
```

You can also put your edit text in the layout and give margins around it.

Answer (score 0):

You have taken two constraintlayout and divided the whole screen in the 90:10 ratio.
If there is no restriction of this fixed ratio then you may change the ratio to 85:15 .

```
 app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.85"
 app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.15"
```

Full EditText is visible in the later case.

Comment: I have changed it even to 0.6,0.4 to check it. The keyboard just hides the EditText until the point where the text starts inside the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

> you make all edittext in one `linearlayout` with `vertical
>   orientation` and this `lineralayout` make under `scroolview`
>   like ex.

```
<scroolview>
  <linearlayout>
 ---text view your all---
  </linearlayout>
<scroolview>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to your parent container in XML